# Is it possible to use Visual Studio ASP.Net 5 template with ASP.Net 4.6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I really like the way the new VS 2015 ASP.Net 5 templates set up the client side build system. It keeps client-side build system components out of the working folders by publishing only the final assets to the working **wwwroot** folder.

I have to create a new project using ASP.Net 4.6 but would like to setup the same build system for node dependencies and bower/gulp components.

Is it possible to convert the ASP.Net 5 empty project to use ASP.Net 4.6 in the same separated way?

Comment: Have you tried http://sidewaffle.com/ there are lots of template to serve what you may need.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just use ASP.net 5? It seems to be a significant improvement over 4 https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to convert the ASP.Net 5 empty project to use ASP.Net 4.6 in the same separated way?

The short answer is "yes", it is possible.

While there are differing versions that have various templates, you could technically achieve what you're looking for by creating your own template.

Visit either of the two MSDN references below for a step-by-step on creating custom template(s):

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

The slightly longer answer "yes, but with some noteworthy caveats".

From within **Visual Studio 2015** navigate `File > New Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application`, then select from the **ASP.NET 5 Templates** "Web Application".

[image: New ASP.NET Project - Web Application]

Open the `project.json` file and change the `frameworks` from this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

To this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },
```

Now you have the desired template that is targeting the `.NET 4.6` runtime environment. One major note and disclaimer is that even though you're targeting `.NET 4.6` this is not `ASP.NET 4.6`, in fact it is still a [`DNX`](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/overview.html) project and uses the latest `ASP.NET Core 1.0` libraries, it just so happens that you're instructing it to run on-top of a known `.NET 4.6` runtime.

`ASP.NET Core 1.0` (formally known as `ASP.NET 5`), is a complete re-write and is still currently only in **RC1** as of 3/09/2016. With that said, there is much more IDE support and tooling yet to come with **RC2** and the final version. It should be understood that `ASP.NET Core 1.0` is not `ASP.NET 4.6`.

Comment: The second part of your answer just isn't practical. However, from what you are saying the first part of your answer might be a possibility. Although from what i can remember, building templates in VS is a dreadful experience and would likely take longer to figure out than would be worth my time in the end. It'll at least be looking into it as it sounds like it may be possible to do what I'm wanting.

Comment: @BradBamford, the bounty ends in a few hours -- does my answer not address your question?

Comment: Can compiled/published web site run under an IIS 7.5 with and .NET 4.6 but without asp.net Core instaled on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. Each Version of Asp.Net has its own template. But you can maybe find an Asp.Net 4.6 template in the internet that looks like the Asp.Net 5 template (if the design and structure is what you mean)